# Running cucumberJS feature files in parallel

Tags: selenium, protractor, cucumberjs, parallel-testing

I am wondering if CucumberJS can handle running feature files in parallel. Currently, we handle parallel testing by using a handful of Jenkins jobs that point to different test directories at the same time and pass it to the selenium grid hub. This works since the hub will now handle the requests it receives and run them in a sort of forced "parallel." The main goal that we want is to run our tests, and set up a max number of sessions, say 4, so that way there are 4 feature files that can essentially run at one time.

I know that cucumber does not have good support for this, and I am doubtful that cucumberjs will - but I am sure there is some sort of npm module out there that someone has had some success with. Any help would be of great benefit to my team and the rare to find cucumberjs/protractor users elsewhere!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using CucumberJS with Protractor you can enable this with:

- using [multiCapabilities](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/config.ts#L320), see for example [here](https://github.com/wswebcreation/protractor-cucumber-typescript-boilerplate/blob/master/e2e-tests/config/protractor.e2e.conf.js)
- and adding `shardTestFiles: true`, see [here](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/config.ts#L285) to your capabilities
- Use `maxInstances` [here](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/config.ts#L296) to limit the max amount of the same browser that are pulled up in parallel
- and use `maxSessions` [here](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/config.ts#343) to limit the max amount of the drivers that are pulled up in parallel